# Rspec Puppet: Defined Type iteration

Tags: puppet, rspec-puppet

- Using Puppet 3
- Testing using rspec-puppet
- Iterating over an array of hashes using a Defined Type
- Getting an Error, telling me that my parameter (which defaults to the value of $title) cannot be accessed the way I am because it is not an Array or Hash

I'm using old-style iteration in a puppet module, creating a defined type to iterate over an array of hashes.  I'm trying to write a test for this define in rspec-puppet, attempting to assign a hash to the `:title` using `let()`.  The `$title` is then supposed to be set to my variable called `$daemon`, yet my tests keep throwing errors saying that `$daemon` is not a hash or array.

Here's how I'm creating my defined type:

```rb
define my_module::daemon_install ($daemon = $title) {

  package {"${daemon['package_name']}":
    ensure => "${daemon['package_version']}",
  }

  file {"${some_fact}/${daemon['binary']}.conf":
    ensure => file,
    content => "blah"
    notify => Service["${daemon['name']}"],
  }

  service {"${daemon['name']}":
    ensure => running,
    enable => true,
  }
}
```

And here's how I'm trying to set the title:

```rb
describe 'my_module::daemon_install' do

  context 'with foo' do

    let(:title) {
      {
        "name" => "foo",
        "package_name" => "bar",
        "package_version" => "1.0.1",
        "binary" => "food",
      }
    }

    # ...

  end
end
```

And here's the error:

`daemon is not a hash or array when accessing it with package_version`

I'm actually abit new to using defined types for iteration, and very new at rspec-puppet, so I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious here or not.

But why is it only complaining about `package_version` and not `package_name`?  And more importantly: why is it not a hash, when (I believe) I'm setting it to a hash correctly in the spec file.

I should mention that another test, of a class which uses this defined type, completes successfully.  So it seems related to how I'm trying to set the title when directly testing the define, if I were to guess.

Answer (score 1):

Rspec always converts `title` into `String`.

Use `$name` in `define()` instead of `$title` and add the following into tests:

```
let :title do
  { ... }
end

let :params do
  { :name => title }
end
```

Please note`$name` should be equal of `$title`.